# Blowing up the bad guys on their turf in a selfless act

Tags: first-appearance, trope

In these three relatively recent movies: Pacific Rim, Independence Day and The Avengers,

> the good guys win by sending a nuke through some orifice to blow up the bad guys on their side of things in what seems like an act of self sacrifice (though in all 3 cases, the prospective martyr-to-be survives).

What is the origin of wrapping up a major conflict (typically a war) with a self-sacrifice to deliver a final blow (via nuke or otherwise)? What is the earliest iteration and what other developmental instances are there in movies?

Comment: I'm not sure what trope you're looking for..."pure self-sacrifice"...."saving the day by blowing stuff up". Could you clarify.

Comment: The whole trope of heroic sacrifice is older than dirt.

Comment: The question was designed to ask not about self-sacrifice per se, but about going to the opposing side to deliver the destruction (on their turf) as that separates these three from any generic martyr.

Comment: Heroic stupidity,  heroic suicide, behind enemy lines. All older than movies.

Comment: @cde Indeed, old war movies are full of it. WW2 bombers crashing into factories, ammo dumps etc. etc.

Comment: It seems so common that in war movies having multiple character, I expect atleast one to give such sacrifice.  It is inspired from actual events